# No hay razón para este error: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

este es mi código:

```
<?php session_start();
```

Así empieza mi archivo php, sin embargo me sale ese error del título, que yo sepa ese error sale si pones algo antes del session_start(); pero no hay nada, aunque un detalle que ví es que me sale un `<br>` antes del mensaje de error, y después esto `#xFEFF;`, pero en mi código no hay ninguna etiqueta br, no entiendo que pasa, además ese error me sale en todas las páginas php que tengo y ni una tiene nada antes del session. Lo tengo alojado en FreeHostingNoAds.

Comment: ¿Has probado de ejecutar este codigo en un server local? Lo digo para descartar si es un error de tu código o de la configuración del server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que la codificación era diferente, el símbolo `#$xFEFF;` representa un espacio en blanco en otra codificación al que yo había trabajado, el problema se resolvió escribiendo manualmente `<?php session_start();` y guardando sobreescribiendo el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes configurada tu sesión para ser validada en cualquier pagina? si es asi solo instanciala con un include asi

```
include_once 'sesion.php';
```

y con eso tendria que funcionar sin necesidad de poner el `session_start();`

el codigo de esa pagina que te comento podria venir asi

```
<?php

$URL_ = "localhost:8282";

session_start(); //valida si esta activa la seci?n, sino, no le deja seguir viendo la data y lo regresa a loginDEj.php
if (isset($_SESSION['ses_id_usuario'])
&& isset($_SESSION['ses_rfc_corto'])
&& isset($_SESSION['ses_correo'])
&& isset($_SESSION['ses_nombre'])
&& isset($_SESSION['ses_id_perfil'])
&& isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])
&& isset($_SESSION["ses_id_depto"]) 
&& isset($_SESSION["ses_id_sub_admin"])
&& isset($_SESSION['ses_id_admin'])
|| isset($_SESSION['ses_jefe_directo'])
|| isset($_SESSION['estatus_ent'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['ses_id_perfil'] != 1) {
        $inactivo = 3600;
        $vida_session = time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'];
       
         $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
            //Removemos sesi�n.
            session_unset();
            //Destruimos sesi�n.
            session_destroy();
            //Redirigimos pagina.
            header("Location: http://$URL_/Proyecto/login.php?error=8");

            die();
    

        
    }
} else {
   header("location:http://$URL_/Proyecto/login.php?error=7");
    
    exit();
}
?>
```

Pero solo es para ser practicos y no estar instanciado la funcion `session_start()` y poder validar y traer todas tus varibles de sesion que quieras.